# how do you set up a address hostname for user on with ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: permissions, 22.04, username

I am on a generation project and on this server, you can check the x version with root permissions with code `sudo x` The version I tried twice and it failed to say `unable to resolve host: no address with hostname`

I am so confused what do I need to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Run the command `sudo x`? What is `x`? Does `sudo` for other commands work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a name resolution issue.
You probably need to fix your /etc/hosts file (easiest option).
If you could post the current content of it I can tell for sure.
The content of /etc/hosts has higher priority over /etc/resolv.conf (either generated by NetworkManager or manually created) so it's probably a better option for a quick fix.